# Suppressing log messages when using support library

Tags: java, android, api, logging

If I want to run something on devices running API 7 level OS , but I use methods or class only available from API 11 , so I use support library to overcome this issue.But the thing is I still get log messages regarding that, is there any way to suppress only this kind of messages ? 
Or is suppressing them will suppress other messages as well?

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you want to supress log messages, + suppressing will not suppress any other log messages or exceptions associated with that.

Comment: It's just a task I was given.. prevent printing those log messages 
 
Thanks!